# How to list all the RDS snapshots through CLI and import some of those fields into a spreadsheet

Tags: excel, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli

I need to list all these ( ( DBSnapshotIdentifier , DBInstanceIdentifier, AvailabilityZone , SnapshotType , Encrypted , SnapshotCreateTime) properties of both automated and manual snapshots of all the available clusters and import this data into a spreadsheet.

I tried `aws rds describe-db-snapshots` this command but I need to get those properties alone and also import those to a spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

Use the regular cli command and save it into a json file. `aws rds describe-db-snapshots > filename.json` and then [convert JSON to CSV via the Command Line Using JQ](https://earthly.dev/blog/convert-to-from-json/)